# not able to save name and email in addressBook using AddressBook framework

Tags: ios, iphone

In my application, i am trying to save name and contact number to address book.

However, when saving (using the below code), i am getting the error:

```
/Users/mobility/Desktop/STAXApplication/STAXApplication/AccountsAndContactsViewController.m:739:61: Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *' to C pointer type 'CFTypeRef' (aka 'const void *') requires a bridged cast
```

The code i am using is:

```
-(void)addRecord:(NSString *)name email:(NSString *)email number:(NSString *)number
{
    NSString *Name = name;
    NSString *Email = email;
    NSString *Number = number;

    ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();

    ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, Name, NULL);
    ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty, Email, nil);

    //ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty, @"agrawal", NULL);
    //ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, CFNu,NULL);

    ABMutableMultiValueRef multiPhone =     ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);

    ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(multiPhone, Number, kABPersonPhoneMainLabel, NULL);

    ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, multiPhone,nil);

    ABAddressBookAddRecord(_addressBook, newPerson, NULL);

    BOOL saved = ABAddressBookSave(_addressBook, NULL);

    if(saved == YES)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Saved" message:@"the contact has been saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" Not Saved" message:@"Not saved" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

There is some king of conversion conflict between NSString and const void*. How to do this conversion?? I used UTF8String too.. but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bridge cast in following way

```
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, (__bridge CFStringRef) Name, NULL);
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonEmailProperty, (__bridge CFStringRef) Email, nil);
```